# Service Pack 1Ð? What does Ð stand for?

Tags: windows-7, special-characters, service-pack

While looking at some crash reports, I saw that one of the users has "Windows 7 Service Pack 1Ð". I thought that maybe it's a buffer overflow bug, but after googling for "Service Pack 1Ð", I saw that some other users have this, although not too many.

What does this Ð symbol mean? Is it specific to some locale?

Comment: Looks like a wrong code-page. Likely it's some Unicode text that's shown in the wrong encoding. In particular, I've seen the Ð sign before in subtitles that had the wrong encoding, but not sure which one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195237/how-do-i-transform-%C3%90%C2%A2%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91-it-is-russian-word-into-something-readable

Comment: @sashoalm look at [this file](http://board.de.elsword.gameforge.com/index.php?page=Attachment&attachmentID=81) for example. The encoding is OK (Windows-1250), there are non-ASCII words like `Brücke`. But still, there's `Service Pack 1Đ` in the file.

Comment: All the other symbols are english characters. The latin alphabet is written the same way in UTF-8 and all the code pages. That's the beauty of UTF-8, even the wrong encoding will display latin characters correctly. I think the first 128 chars are the same for all encodings.

Comment: `ü` in `Brücke`, being a non-ASCII character, is not part of "the first 128 chars".

Comment: Oh, ok, I had missed that. Btw, why does it have a `7600.win7_gdr.100618`? Does it stand for GDR?

Comment: GDR = General distribution release. this is a normal update. 7600 means that this is a Windows 7 without Sp1. Sp1 has buildnumber 7601.

Comment: Provide this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Eth in Icelandic and Faroese. Almost equal to "The" in English. It's in the ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1) encoding.

I have seen this occur in pirated x64 Ultimate Editions, burned on dual layer burners.

Comment: So... it's a badly-localized version of "Service Pack the First"? Or... something? The hell?

Comment: Not sure. Ð = D0 in hex, 208 dec. Windows-1250 encoding will be Ă. But it should say "Windows Service Pack 1.".

Converted to hex "Windows Service Pack 1." = "57696e646f77732053657276696365205061636b20312e", "Windows Service Pack 1Đ" = "57696E646F77732053657276696365205061636B2031D0".

In cp-1250, utf-8 gives another result but if I change it to Legacy ASCII or Legacy DOS I get the correct translation, both display correct.

Both are identical in binary format:
0101011101101001011011100110010001101111011101110111001100100000

0101011101101001011011100110010001101111011101110111001100100000

Comment: So if they are identical in binary it has something to do with the translation.